# TCP "Client" example in Clojure!

Tags: clojure, client-server

I am trying to use a TCP socket to communicate a shared state between a server and a bunch of clients. I am using "Server-Socket" from clojure.contrib for the server. That works pretty well and I can communicate with the server with other tools.

I am having a rather hard time finding good examples for client-side socket use in Clojure.

I actually "print" and "read-stirng" the state vector back and forth.

What is the "Clojure" way to do do the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found "saturine" very useful  https://github.com/texodus/saturnine

Saturnine is a Clojure library designed to facilitate rapid development of asynchronous network applications. It is built on top of JBoss Netty, and inherits a number of features from this framework, but is designed with simplicity in mind.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the "[Simple Clojure IRC Client](http://nakkaya.com/2010/02/10/a-simple-clojure-irc-client/)" will be of help?